# How to make a bundle of circle on the left side of the text using css

Tags: css, css-shapes

Is it possible to make this using css only:

[image]

Sorry for my bad english. Please help, I dont have any idea to do this.

I can only make 2 circles on the left side of the text using this code:

```
.header3-title{
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:17px;
}

.header3-title:before{
    content:''; 
    border-radius:30px;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
    -moz-border-radius:30px; 
    height:8px; 
    width:8px; 
    display:block; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:5px; 
    left:6px; 
    background-color:#ff7819;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header3-title:after{
    content:''; 
    border-radius:30px;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
    -moz-border-radius:30px; 
    height:8px; 
    width:8px; 
    display:block; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    left:2px; 
    background-color:#0a78dc;
}
```

Comment: You may bring code to SO and ask why it's not working the way (you think) it should. You may not come here and ask "Code this for me".

Comment: Sorry, I already make a code of my problem above. But, I only can make 2 cirlce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single pseudo and box-shadow

```css
h1 {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0AB8DB, #0A7CDC);
  color: white;
  text-indent: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  /* for demo */
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
h1::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1em;
  left: 0.2em;
  width: 0.25em;
  height: 0.25em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #F97916;
  box-shadow: 0 0.35em #F97916, 0.35em 0 #F97916, 0.7em 0 #0277C7, 0 0.7em #0277C7, 0.35em 0.35em #0277C7
}
h1 + h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<h1>test circles</h1> 
<h1>Why em ? ... because </h1>
```

Comment: I like this one very much!

Comment: @GCyrillus I like this one too, can you explain me which part of your code that will generate the circles? sorry I really don't understand.

Comment: Look at the box-shadow values. The different hex color codes are representing the colors of the circles. em values are the vertical and horizontal offsets.

Answer (score 2):

**Pseudo-element method:**

You can use `::after` and `::before` pseudo-element to achieve the output in the image.

`content` property in `::after` will hold your text and the `::before` content will produce your set of circles. `/a` can be used to create the new lines for the circles.

```css
.circle-text::before {
  color: white;
  content: "●●●\a ●●\a ●"; /* \a is used to create a new line */
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: pre; /* Preserve white space */
}
.circle-text::after {
  content: "Text after circle";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
.circle-text {
  background: lightblue;
  line-height: 8px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-text"></div>
```

**Regular CSS method:**

*Pros: You can change the color of each circle which you cannot do in pseudo-element method.*

```css
.circle {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
}
.circle:nth-child(3),
.circle:nth-child(6),
.circle:nth-child(8) {
  background-color: #0B7BDD;
}
.circles {
  line-height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.text {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
.container {
  background: lightblue none repeat scroll 0 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circles">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="text">Text after circle</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :), I prefer to use the :after and :before pseudo elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very doable. Just needs some positioning and border-radius, such as

`position: absolute; 
 left: 50px;
 border-radius: 100%`

Comment: Leaving aside that requests such as this one should not be answered on SO (this is not what SO is about), your code is quite far from creating what the OP asked for. Giving an incomplete answer is usually worse  than no answer at all, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using **svg** to create this shape.

```html
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="10" fill="orange"></circle>
  <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="10" fill="orange"></circle>
  <circle cx="75" cy="25" r="10" fill="blue"></circle>
  <circle cx="25" cy="50" r="10" fill="orange"></circle>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10" fill="blue"></circle>
  <circle cx="25" cy="75" r="10" fill="blue"></circle>
</svg>
```

With text and background-color:

```css
.container {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, cornflowerblue, rgb(10, 100, 200));
  height: 50px;
}
.container svg {
  float: left;
}
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg width="50px" height="50px" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="10" fill="orange"></circle>
    <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="10" fill="orange"></circle>
    <circle cx="75" cy="25" r="10" fill="blue"></circle>
    <circle cx="25" cy="50" r="10" fill="orange"></circle>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10" fill="blue"></circle>
    <circle cx="25" cy="75" r="10" fill="blue"></circle>
  </svg>
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dollar si amet</div>
</div>
```